# How to send custom cookies in a fetch request

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch

Can I make a fetch request with 'custom' cookies not set on my browser?

For example:

```js
fetch('/foo', {
  credentials: 'omit', // I don't want to send my real cookies
  headers: {
    cookie: 'foo=bar'
  }
})
```

The `cookie` header doesn't seem to be set when executing this fetch request with `credentials: 'omit'`.

---

I am aware I could save my current cookies, set new cookies, make the fetch request and restore the cookies... but is there a better way?

Eg.

```js
const oldCookies = document.cookie
document.cookie = 'foo=bar'
fetch('/foo')
document.cookie = oldCookies
```

Answer (score 0):

With the same origin, the browser side `fetch` will always use the `document.cookie`.

The `Cookie` header is one of the [forbidden headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), which cannot be modified programmatically in browser side.  This rule doesn't apply to the server side. The following code can be tested on the Chrome DevTools Console of page https://httpbin.org/. As for a different origin, fetch won't send any cookie.

#### create a test cookie foo=bar

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/foo/bar')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)));
```

#### test

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org/cookies', {
  headers: {
    Cookie: 'xxx=yyy'
  }
}).then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)));
```

Answer (score -5):

Try with omit or include:

```
fetch('/foo', {
  credentials: 'omit', // I don't want to send my real cookies
  headers: {
    'Set-Cookie': 'foo=bar'
  }
})
```

Comment: Set cookie header appears in the request information of Chrome dev tools, but it is not really being set as a cookie.

Comment: Did you try with credentials: 'include', ?

Comment: Include seems to add my existing cookies, but `foo=bar;` is not being sent.

Comment: using a response header in a request won't ever change how a request works